# Writing a Vector (Math) Class in Python

Tags: python, list, class

Here is my Vector class

```
class Vector:
   def __init__(self, *v):
        self.v = v
```

It works great for things such as:

```
v = Vector(1, 1, 1)
```

where self.v prints out a list

How would I change it so that:

```
v = Vector([1, 1, 1])
```

it prints out a list. 
Currently, it prints out a list within a list.

Comment: let u and v be Vectors. Should I make u * v be the dot product of make a function dot(u,v) compute the dot product?

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Iterable

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, *v):
        if len(v) == 1 and isinstance(v[0], Iterable) and not isinstance(v[0], str):
            # iterable (but not string) - cast to list
            self.v = list(v[0])
        else:
            self.v = v
```

Comment: Almost...
`>>> Vector([1,1,1]).v`
`[[1, 1, 1]]`

Comment: Yes, I just fixed that ;-)

Comment: Perfect. The only thing I'd point out is that passing a string is perfectly valid, and since this is a math class, it might be worth throwing a `ValueError` for a string, but we can leave that up to OP

Answer (score 0):

Since `*v` will give multiple positional argument, if you don't want to loose this property you can check it the length of `v` is 1 then just assign the first item to `self.v`:

```
class Vector:
   def __init__(self, *v):
        self.v = v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v
```

Also note that this expression might raise some exceptions based on the type of `v` So as a more pythonic and safer way you better to use a `try-except` expression to handle the exceptions.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable # In python 2.x collections import Iterable

    class Vector:
       def __init__(self, *v):
            try:
                self.length = len(v)
            except TypeError:
                self.v = v
            else:
                 if isinstance(v, Iterable):
                     self.v = v[0] if self.length == 1 else v
                 else:
                     self.v = v
```

Comment: thanks. this works. however,  def __init__(self, *v):
        self.v = v[0] if len(v) == 1 else list(v), works for me in this case.

Comment: @JohnVo Yes but I added a more complete approach which will handle all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your class to behave differently when it's passed a single list than when it's passed multiple numbers, you need to put some conditional logic in your `__init__` method. Something like this might work (though there are other ways you could do the checking):

```
def __init__(self, *v):
    if len(v) == 1:
        v = v[0]

    self.v = v
```

Obviously this won't work as expected for a 1-dimensional Vector (`v` will be set to the single scalar value, rather than a 1-valued list). You could probably use `isinstance` to make sure the single value is in fact a list or tuple if you want, but I suspect there would still be awkward corner cases you'd get wrong.

A better approach may be to change the code that wants to pass in a list. If instead of `Vector([1,1,1])`, you did `Vector(*[1,1,1])`, your existing code would work just fine.